# How to use Gsub in R to sort ages

Tags: r

I have a vector of ages and I want to use gsub to sort through the ages under 21. I would like to sub 'no' in for all ages under 21.

```
ages <- c(3,45,12,28,14,19,40,22)
gsub(ages < 21,"no" , ages)
```

I receive the error "argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used". I'm new at R and I'm trying to figure out these commands.

Comment: Perhap you need `ifelse` or `replace` i.e. `replace(ages, ages < 21, "no")`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You could do it with `gsub` in the following way `gsub("^\\d$|1\\d","no",ages)`  but it would be more difficult to read and more error-prone, Another way could be `ages[ages<21] <- "no"` but it will destroy the original ages vector. In my opinion @akrun method would be a good method.

Comment: @DJJ your `gsub` fails for 20.

Comment: As already stated by others, `gsub` isn't the right function for this. Also by adding "no" in `ages` vector you are changing it to a character vector.

Comment: @Edward nice  catch then `gsub("^\\d$|1\\d|20","no",ages)` would do.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be very useful, because it does not use the gsub function, but you can use the following code for what you are looking for:

```
ifelse(ages < 21, "no", ages)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually a warning and stems from the fact that `gsub` isn't vectorized and wants a single argument (`length 1`) where you give it a vector of `TRUE/FALSE` of `length(ages)`. You also feed `gsub` with a condition, although it wants a pattern that it should replace. So if you want to replace e.g. `19` with `"no"` you want to do `gsub("^19$", "no", ages)`. The `^`, `$` at the edges are needed to mark start and end of the string, otherwise it also would replace e.g. `119`.

Now, since you have many possible ages below 21, you need to define all those possibilities, separated by an `|` for "or": `^1$|^2$|^3$|...`. The `paste` function helps you.

So if you are dependent on `gsub` you may do:

```
ages <- gsub(paste0("^", 1:20, "$", collapse="|"), "no", ages)
# [1] "no" "45" "no" "28" "no" "no" "40" "22"
```

If `ages` have decimals, replace `1:20` with something like `seq(1, 20, .1)` depending on decimal places.

Patterns such as `"^1$"` are called *regular expressions*, you may find out more of them by typing `?regex` into your R console.

However, it's probably more easy to do:

```
ages[ages < 21] <- "no"
```